# IOS Screen Time to get duration for app used

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, native

I've been working on Flutter for quite sometime and I've no relevant experience when it comes to native side or iOS. I wanted the suggestion that is it possible for me to use screen time IOS feature in custom app where I can see how much time one has spent on app in his device, like for Android we've a package called app_usage.
Help appreciated.

Comment: The screen time api does not provide any data on app usage. It would be a privacy violation.

Comment: so is there any other functionality that provide me the usage time of all the apps in my phone? @Paulw11

Comment: no.  it would be a privacy violation to provide that information.  Apple could, in theory, put such data behind a user approval, like location, but at the moment they have not.